# What's the point of `viewable_range` concept?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, range-v3

[[range.refinements]](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.refinements)

> The viewable_­range concept specifies the requirements of a range type that can be converted to a view safely.

It's mandatory implementation roughly states that a `range` further satisfies `viewable_range` if either

1. it's simply a view, e.g. `std::string_view`, or
2. it's an lvalue reference (even when its reference-removed type is not a view), e.g. `std::vector<int>&`, or
3. it's a movable object type (i.e. not reference type), e.g. `std::vector<int>`

My questions are:

1. What idea does this concept capture? Specifically, how could its instance "be converted to a view safely" and why do I want such conversion? What does "safety" even mean here?
2. Do you always use `viewable_range` to constrain universal reference? (i.e. the only chance `T` to be deduced to lvalue reference type.) This is the case for standard range adaptor (closure) objects.
3. Range adaptor (closure) objects are modified to take a `range` as first parameter in C++23. Is there other usage for `viewable_range` concept since then?
4. For application development, when to use `viewable_range` instead of `view` or `range`?

Comment: Most views don't actually own elements, they just contain a pointer to the underlying range. `viewable_range` allows us to convert the range into a `view` without worrying about dangling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What idea does this concept capture? Specifically, how could its instance "be converted to a view safely" and why do I want such conversion? What does "safety" even mean here?

Any range *can* be converted to a view, simply by doing this:

```cpp
template <input_range R>
auto into_view(R&& r) {
    return ref_view(r);
}
```

But this isn't really a great idea. If we had an rvalue range (whether it's a view or not), now we're taking a reference to it, so this could dangle if we hold onto the resulting view too long.

In general, we don't want to hold onto references to `view`s - the point of a `view` is that range adaptors hold them by value, not by reference. But also in general, we don't want to hold non-view ranges by value, since those are expensive to copy.

What `viewable_range` does is restrict the set of ranges to those where we can covert to a view without added concern for dangling:

- `view`s should always be by value - so an lvalue `view` is only a `viewable_range` if it is copyable. An rvalue `view` is always a `viewable_range` (because `view`s have to be movable).
- an *lvalue* non-`view` range is always a `viewable_range` because we take a `ref_view` in that case. This of course has potential for dangling, but we're taking an lvalue, so it's the safer case.
- an *rvalue* non-`view` range was originally rejected (because our only option was `ref_view` and we don't want to refer in this case), but will start to be captured as `owning_view` (as of [P2415](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2415r2.html)).

So basically, the only thing that isn't a viewable range is an lvalue non-copyable view, because of the desire to avoid taking references to views.

> Do you always use `viewable_range` to constrain <s>universal</s> forwarding reference? (i.e. the only chance T to be deduced to lvalue reference type.) This is the case for standard range adaptor (closure) objects.

No. Only if what you want to do with the forwarding reference is convert it to a view and store the resulting view. Range adaptors do this, but algorithms don't need to - so they shouldn't use that constraint (none of the standard library algorithms do).

> Range adaptor (closure) objects are modified to take a range as first parameter in C++23. Is there other usage for viewable_range concept since then?

The *term* range adaptor closure object is relaxed because now that we can have user-defined range adaptor closure objects ([P2387](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2387r3.html)), we can't really enforce what it is that they actually do.

But the standard library range adaptor closure objects still do require `viewable_range` (by way of `all_t`).

> For application development, when to use `viewable_range` instead of `view` or `range`?

This is really the same question as (2). If what you want is to take any range and convert it to a view to be stored, you use `viewable_range` - so when you're writing a range adaptor.

Comment: Hi, Barry. So if the underlying non-view range destructs first, all `view`s over it dangle anyway - even they satisfy `viewable_range`? Then how `T` satisfying `viewable_range` makes it safer to take `ref_view<T>` ? Or put my question in another way - how does not satisfying `viewable_range` adds to the concern of dangling?