# Why is passing rvalue range that is not viewable range to range adaptor allowed in latest compiler?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I am learning about ranges and as I learned about range adaptors, they only accept `viewable_range` as the first argument according to [cppreference RangeAdaptorObject](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RangeAdaptorObject).

But when I tested this code on Compiler Explorer:

```
auto val = std::views::drop(std::vector{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 2);
```

I found that for clang 16.0.0 and gcc 12.0 (both with `-std=c++20`), this code does compile, while for any older version it does not.

I also tried:

```
auto val = std::views::transform(std::vector{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 2);
```

This does not compile for any versions of compilers.

So why is it allowed to passing non-viewable_range to some range adaptors in newer version of compiler?

update:

Thanks for @康桓瑋 to point out my typo, `views::transform` does compile with rvalue movable range:

```
auto val = std::views::transform(std::vector{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, [](int i) { return i; });
```

Comment: I believe a `std::vector<int>` is a viewable range.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73537755/whats-the-point-of-viewable-range-concept

Comment: @TimRoberts thank you, I see my mistakes here, and it seems that `std::views::transform` has stricter requirements, it requires the first argument to be a view object, so that is why it does not work for `std::views::transform`

Comment: `views::transform` takes a callable as a second parameter instead of the integer. So this is just a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++20 DR (Defect Report) [P2415](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2415r2.html) enhances the definition of [`viewable_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/viewable_range) to:

```
template<class T>
  concept viewable_range =
    range<T> &&
    ((view<remove_cvref_t<T>> && constructible_from<remove_cvref_t<T>, T>) ||
     (!view<remove_cvref_t<T>> &&
      (is_lvalue_reference_v<T> || (movable<remove_reference_t<T>> && !is-initializer-list<T>))));
```

Note the last part:

```
(!view<remove_cvref_t<T>> &&
  (is_lvalue_reference_v<T> || (movable<remove_reference_t<T>> && !is-initializer-list<T>))));
```

We no longer require that the non-`view` range must be an lvalue reference, in which case a new move-only [`owning_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/owning_view) was introduced to handle such cases.

`owning_view` will move the rvalue non-`view` range to its internal member to take ownership of the data, and make the transfer of ownership only through the move operation, which still meets the semantic requirements of the [`view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/view) updated by the paper.

So in C++20, an rvalue `vector` is also a `viewable_range` because it can be converted to `owning_view`.

As your example, `views::drop(std::vector{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 2)` will first move the rvalue `vector` into `owning_view`, then moves `owning_view` into `drop_view`. Since the `drop_view` regains ownership of the data, it is also move-only.

Comment: And the owning view will in turn keep the underlying vector alive, as would the returned object?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Exactly. `owning_view` moves the `vector` to its own member to take ownership of the data and makes transfers of ownership only via moves, which still meets the (updated by P2415) definition of a `view`.

Comment: Can you add this to the answer?  It is implied, but the behavior change being linked to the 'can it compile' change makes the change make sense.